# How to increase stack size when compiling a C++ program using MinGW compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, stack-overflow

I am trying to compile a program that was provided to me. The program tests the run time of the algorithm quicksort when provided different values. I need to increase the size of the stack to run really large numbers.

I read to use the following command: `g++ -Wl,--stack,<size>`

where size is the number to increase the stack.

However, this isn't working for me. In command prompt when I typed exactly the following:

`g++ -Wl,--stack,1000000000`

and then hit enter, I get the following message:

> C:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0):
>   undefined reference to 'WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

I am not allowed to change the code so my only option is to increase the stack size in command prompt and then run my code.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Am I typing in the command incorrectly?

How do I increase the stack size in command prompt for a c++ program using MinGW compiler? I am using Windows 10, if that information is helpful.

Comment: Does it work for smaller values of stack size?

Comment: Yes it works for small values like 10,000. If I try 1,000,000 it simply doesn't work. I don't get an error message or anything, the program just ends.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you keep halving the stack size until you find a value that produces a working exe and see if that runs without running out of stack space.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. I posted the answer below in case someone else has the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the size of the stack to run a C++ program that may cause a stack overflow, use the following command.

```
g++ -Wl,--stack,16777216 -o file.exe file.cpp
```

This increases the stack size to 16MiB, if you need it to be bigger then increase the value from `16777216` bytes to whatever value you need.

Do be sure to replace `file.exe` and `file.cpp` with the corresponding names of the file and executable that you are running.

Also note that in the command its `-Wl` (lower case L)

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -Wl,--stack,1000000000 -o main.exe main.cpp
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).