# Getting stackoverflow error when I use for loop but if the same thing is done using an if block no error is produced

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, stack-overflow

I was solving a DSA problem 
the language I'm using is java SE
link:https://www.codingninjas.com/studio/problems/ninja-s-training_3621003
I know my solution is correct but for one of the test cases(I dont know what the test case is as it doesnt display the test case) I run into a stackoverflow error so I just replaced the for loop with a few if statements and it fixed it, I want to know why I ran into the error in first place

**also the same solution(with for loop) in c++ gives no error, does stack space work differently for java and c++?**

it just doesnt make sense the amount of function calls made remains the same in both the approaches but one gives a stackoverflow error. so there is no way the the number of calls is more than the stack space, If someone could figure this out for me it'd be great

Here is the code with the **for loop**:

```
public class Solution {
    private static int dp[][];
    private static int rec(int day, int prev, int[][] points) {
        if (day == 0) {
            // No more days left.
            return 0;
        }

        if (dp[day][prev] != -1) {
            return dp[day][prev];
        }

        // Merit points of ith task on nth day.
        int ans = points[day - 1][prev - 1];
        int mx = 0;
        for(int k=1;k<4;k++)
        {
            if(k!=prev)
            {
                int cur=rec(day-1, k, points);
                mx=Math.max(cur,mx);
            }
        }
        

        dp[day][prev] = ans + mx;
        return ans + mx;
    }

    public static int ninjaTraining(int n, int points[][]) {
        // DP table to memoize the solution.
        dp = new int[n + 1][4];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        int ans = 0;
        ans = Math.max(ans, rec(n, 1, points));
        ans = Math.max(ans, rec(n, 2, points));
        ans = Math.max(ans, rec(n, 3, points));

        return ans;
    }
}
```

here is the code with **if blocks**:

```
public class Solution {
    private static int dp[][];
    private static int rec(int day, int prev, int[][] points) {
        if (day == 0) {
            // No more days left.
            return 0;
        }

        if (dp[day][prev] != -1) {
            return dp[day][prev];
        }

        // Merit points of ith task on nth day.
        int ans = points[day - 1][prev - 1];
        int mx = 0;
        
        if (prev == 1) {
            mx = Math.max(rec(day - 1, 2, points), rec(day - 1, 3, points));
        }

        if (prev == 2) {
            mx = Math.max(rec(day - 1, 1, points), rec(day - 1, 3, points));
        }

        if (prev == 3) {
            mx = Math.max(rec(day - 1, 1, points), rec(day - 1, 2, points));
        }

        dp[day][prev] = ans + mx;
        return ans + mx;
    }

    public static int ninjaTraining(int n, int points[][]) {
        // DP table to memoize the solution.
        dp = new int[n + 1][4];
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = -1;
            }
        }
        int ans = 0;
        ans = Math.max(ans, rec(n, 1, points));
        ans = Math.max(ans, rec(n, 2, points));
        ans = Math.max(ans, rec(n, 3, points));

        return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution uses extra local variables `k` and `cur`, which are allocated on the stack for each execution context of the recursive function. This means your stack grows a bit faster than with the second solution.

> does stack space work differently for java and c++?

Yes, each language environment manage their stacks with their own limits. They often allow to change the maximum size of the stack too. See [for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20030120/5459839) and [for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54821412/5459839).

Note that you can also avoid the `if` blocks and deal with the three cases in one go:

```
int mx = Math.max(rec(day - 1, prev % 3 + 1, points), 
                  rec(day - 1, (prev + 1) % 3 + 1, points));
```

You can reduce more stack space if you store `points` as a static variable (just like `dp`) and don't pass it as argument to your recursive function.

Comment: thank you so much, it makes sense, So by default c++(256 bytes) has a larger stack size than java(512kb) right? and also after reading this I modified the code with only one extra variable(k) and it still gave me a stack-overflow error. I am shocked to see a single extra integer variable cause a stack overflow error, its just 4 bytes!!

Comment: Yes, but if you have 4 more bytes in one stackframe, this multiplies over all nested recursive calls. So if you have like 100 nested recursive calls, these 4 bytes translate to 400 bytes. In your case it just shows you were near the limit, and any slight change could bring you to the "other side" of the limit. Comparing C++ and Java is also not that straightforward, as Java has memory overhead for arrays and objects that is different from C++. They have their own "header" with meta data.

Comment: yep makes sense, Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

Stack used to get your recursive function result to assign to `int cur` is overflowed due to a potentially big input number `n` in your tests.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow